# How does dependent object destructuring assignment work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, destructuring, object-destructuring

This is apparently a valid destructuring assignment despite `qux` depending on `bar`:

```js
const { foo, bar, qux = () => bar } = myObject;
```

How does this work since the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) does not cover how dependent assignments like the example above works.

Comment: Note that your example is slightly misleading, `qux` will still be `() => 'qux'`.

Comment: @Etheryte Yes, I am aware of that. Perhaps my example is a little confusing because of that?

Comment: Yep, it works from left to right, but since this is a function, it doesn’t evaluate the variable right away. `const { foo, bar, qux = () => baz } = myObject;` is just as valid, so is `const { foo, bar, baz = bar } = myObject;`. Note that these default values will be entirely ignored for property names that resolve to `undefined`, anyway. `const { foo, bar = qux, qux } = myObject;` works as long as `myObject.bar` does not resolve to `undefined`. `const { foo, baz = qux, qux } = myObject;` will not work.

Comment: @SebastianSimon That makes a lot more sense after seeing your example of `baz = qux` rather than my example involving the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qux: () => 'qux'` means to declare `const qux`, whose value will be extracted as the property `qux` from `myObject`.

However, if `myObject` has no such property, the const is declared as if you'd just written `const qux = () => bar`. Therefore, the default value of `qux` is an arrow function.

Note that for the default to be used, the `qux` property must be absent or set to undefined in `myObject`. The default will not be used if `qux` in `myObject` is null or any other value.

Also note that this will work:

```js
const { foo, qux = () => bar, bar, x=qux() } = {};
```

But this will throw `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'bar' before initialization`:

```js
const { foo, qux = () => bar, x=qux(), bar } = {};
```

This is because when you do `qux = () => bar`, it's not attempting to access an undeclared variable yet. However, invoking `qux()` does attempt to access the `bar` variable, so the order is important.

Comment: Right, suppose we have  `const { foo, bar, qux = () => bar } = {};` so that `foo, bar = undefined` and `qux = () => undefined`. The result stays the same even if we have `const { foo, qux = () => bar, bar } = {};` despite `bar` coming after `qux`. How does the order work here?

Comment: @fibol80270 that's a really interesting point, I'm adding something to my answer that will appear in a few seconds

Comment: Thanks, that covers all bases for me. Planning on using this with React for default props, so I wanted to make sure I fully understood its behavior before usage.